# iolib import error in python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, statsmodels, pyalgotrade

On Mac OS X Mountain Lion, I try

```
import numpy as np
import os
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

I get this error:

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/idf/PycharmProjects/PyAlgoTrade/GoldvsMiners.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/idf/PycharmProjects/PyAlgoTrade/GoldvsMiners.py", line 9, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as sm
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/statsmodels/api.py", line 1, in <module>
    import iolib, datasets, tools
ImportError: No module named iolib
```

If I add

```
import sys
print("=======")
print sys.path
print("=======")
```

I get

```
=======

['/Users/idf/PycharmProjects/PyAlgoTrade', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytz-2013b-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4-py2.7.egg', '/Users/idf/PycharmProjects/PyAlgoTrade', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
=======
```

I have tried searching the net, but I am stuck on this one. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try installing iolib?

Comment: Ignacio from here? http://www.iolib.org/download.html Also, it seems that I need version 5, since 4 does not support Mac OS X (Darwin cxx?) I tried to build it: make darwin-cxx-shared  Compiling ./iolib-cxx/src/iolib.cpp...error: invalid value '6' in '-O6'
make[1]: *** [iolib-cxx/objects/iolib.o] Error 1
make: *** [darwin-cxx-shared] Error 2

Comment: statsmodels.iolib is a subdirectory of statsmodels with several modules, not a separate package. How did you install statsmodels. iolib has a cython extension that needs to be build, and it is possible that this is not built correctly. Which version of statsmodels? Egg version shows 0.0.0 which I haven't seen before.

Comment: I went about it a different way. I am using virtual environment, and installed everything again inside there. It is still 2.7.2, but it seems to work. I am using just python filename to run it, instead of running it inside PyCharm. I am going to try to use PyCharm next with the virtual environment to see if that works. One thing, scikits.statsmodels is not the same as statsmodel. Thanks.